# How can I know that a file is using or not in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I created a file cleanup function by using health monitoring. It is deleting file that is no access from another process. So, I want to check this. Is it stay access. If not access, I delete this file. How can I do?

Comment: ERROR: THIS FILE IS USING HEROIN (asp.net)

Comment: do you mean "How do I know if a file is in use (by another process) from an asp.net application?" =)

Comment: I appreciate English is probably not you first language but as it stands you question doesn't make a lot of sense. Are you asking if you can tell whether a file is part of an asp.net applicaton or if a file is being accessed by an asp.net application?

Comment: @Neurofluxation, perhaps instead of ridiculing the OP you could consider helping them instead? There's **really** no need for it =)

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do, rather than trying to check to see if a file is locked (as this could change in the time between checking and attempting to delete) is wrap the delete attempt in a `try`/`catch` block:

```
Dim filenameToDelete = "AFileThatsInuse.doc"
Try
    System.IO.File.Delete(filenameToDelete)
Catch ex As IOException
    ' Have some code here that logs the content of the exception to a log file, 
    'the Windows Event Log or sends an email - whatever is appropriate
End Try
```

Note that, rather than catching the generic [`Exception`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.aspx), I've caught [`IOException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ioexception.aspx). This is because the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete.aspx) for `File.Delete` states that you'll get this exception when:

> The specified file is in use.
>
> -or-
>
> There is an open handle on the file,
>   and the operating system is Windows XP
>   or earlier. This open handle can
>   result from enumerating directories
>   and files. For more information, see
>   How to: Enumerate Directories and
>   Files.

You may still want to catch/handle other exception types but it's never a good idea to "blindly" catch and handle Exception, rather than one of its more specific variants.

You could also *attempt to [open the file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y973b725.aspx) to write*, and if that fails then you can tell that the file is already open elsewhere:

```
Try
    System.IO.File.Open("AFileThatsInUse.doc", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None)
Catch ex as IOException
    ' As before, what you do when you determine the file is in use is up to you
End Try
```

This code attempts to open the file exclusively, so if another process has the file open already, it should fail and throw the `IOException` for you.

Comment: thank for information, but I not like this. So, is has another way. I want to check that is using or not.

Comment: @zanhtet, I've just converted the code to VB.net as I remembered that you've tagged the question vb.net. As I said in my answer, there's no sure-fire way to be sure if a file is in use prior to deleting as it could change between *checking* and *deleting*, but I'm going to add an example using the `File.Open` method.

Comment: thank for reply. But I not want to using try catch exception. So, I want to check using "if".

Comment: @zanhtet - why don't you want to by using try/catch? There is no `FileIsInUse` property exposed within the .net Framework (at least as far as I'm aware) - to check with an "If" you would have to either call Win32 code by p/invoke, or *wrap the code I've suggested in a method* that you can then call in an `If`.